# Upload and overwrite CSV in specific location - django app

Tags: python, django, csv, file-upload, web-applications

I currently have a django web app which reads in data from a csv and creates graphs using that data, the file hierarchy looks like this:

```
csvparser
    csvparser
        init.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py

    dataset
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        stored.csv ******
        tests.py
        views.py
```

The csv file that my graphs are made from (stored.csv) is included right in the application's folder, but now I want to have it so that I can upload any csv file (with the same headers) to that location with that name so that my app will do the same thing with an uploaded csv as it does with the current stored.csv.

Essentially I just want to have functionality to upload a csv which overwrites the current stored.csv file at that location, is there an easy way to do this?